# How to have the current selected value option under dropdown in tablepress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I would like to know how to have the selected option value under dropdown after selecting it, because whenever I'm selecting any option, it gets deleted and comes beneath the dropdown option with a link. When you click it, it is going back to the dropdown menu. Code before selection

```
<div class="column-filter-widget">
    <select class="widget-0">
        <option value="">Healthy Life</option>
        <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
        <option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</option>
       <option value="Beef">Beef</option>
    </select>
```

HTML Code after selecting option as "Fruit"

```
<div class="column-filter-widget">
     <select class="widget-0">
         <option value="">Healthy Life</option>
         <option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</option>
         <option value="Beef">Beef</option>
     </select><a class="filter-term filter-term-fruit" href="#">Fruit</a>
 </div>
```

Css Code:

```
  .column-filter-widgets a.filter-term:hover {text-decoration: line-through!important;}
```

Here is the javasript file [Click here](http://pastebin.com/EgtfjkLZ) to check javascript file. I know there are many threads similar to that but since this problem is for Wordpress Plugin tablepress datatables column filter widgets and it's under javascript file which I don't know how to solve. I'm sure the problem can easily be solved after looking at the above link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i'm assuming this what you were after from what i read, here's a JS Fiddle to show you http://jsfiddle.net/7a38ast6/7/

**JQuery**

```
var optionvalue = 0;
var optionvalueclass = ""

$('select.widget-0').change(function(){
    optionvalue = $('option:selected', this).text();
    optionvalue = optionvalue.replace(" ", "-");
    optionvalueclass = optionvalue.toLowerCase();
    $(".widget-0").after('<a class="filter-term filter-term-' + optionvalueclass + '" href="#">' + optionvalue + '</a>');
    $('option:selected', this).remove();
});
```

Comment: The one which you showed is the exact problem which I'm facing right now. When you select any other option, it must not display under link but under dropdown itself. Since it is related to the plugin, you can check the javascript file for the changes. That is where the problem of mine.

Comment: Thanks, very close to my answer. Is it possible that if I select something, then that is display under the same dropdown instead below?